# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'int'

Tags: python

Here is a function of mine:

```
def analyzeHeader(headerLine):
    import re
    matchObj = re.match("^\s*(\w+).+:\s*(\d+)\s+Name = (.+) - Type = (.+)\s*$", headerLine, re.M|re.I)
    if not matchObj:
        return None
    return [matchObj.group(1), matchObj.group(2), matchObj.group(3), matchObj.group(4)]
```

Then I call analyzeHeader:

```
list = analyzeHeader(headerLine)
## ....
col = int(float(list[1])) - 1 ### <== Error here
```

And if I change the above lines to:

```
list = analyzeHeader(headerLine)
## ....
col = float(list[1]) - 1 ### <== OK now
c = int(col)
r = row - 1
tmp = data[r]
res = float(tmp[c]) ### Error now occurs here: "TypeError: list indices must be integers"
```

Any idea what's wrong with this code?

Comment: please put complete error output

Comment: I can't reproduce your error; did you re-assign a subclass of `int()` to `int` perhaps?

Comment: Given that you are doing: `list = analyzeHeader(headerLine)` you probably replaced the `int` type with something else. *Do not use built-in names when defining user classes/objects/variables!*

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code. The tool I use to execute the code just covers the original int() function of Python. Then all I have to do is to call the original int() function: `__builtin__.int()`